# MediaPlay won't play a sound, why?

Tags: android

Here's my code

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
...
try {
mp.setDataSource( getString(R.raw.click));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

yet strangely it give me

```
09-26 16:06:39.316: INFO/ActivityManager(110): Displayed Constructor.rob.com/.constr: +7s443ms
09-26 16:06:40.445: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(76): setDataSource('res/raw/click.mp3')
09-26 16:06:40.453: ERROR/MediaPlayer(21990): error (1, -2147483648)
09-26 16:06:40.457: WARN/System.err(21990): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
mp= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click);
mp.start();
```

Comment: welcome, but if you are playing mediaPlayer continuously, then dont use this, use Soundpool for playing short but many sound clips.., Playing mediaplayer object continuously will cause an error later!!

Answer (score 3):

Add mp.reset() before mp.setDataSource().

EDIT: Wait, what are you doing with getString? You can't do that; to set a data source you need a FileDescriptor. Try this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.click);
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```